# TFS Build where tests rely on office interop

Tags: tfs, msbuild, office-interop

I have a project which contains unit tests which depend on using office interop to mimic the opening and closing of files, post generation.

I am moving this project into an automated TFS build and at the moment it's failing on those tests saying:

```
LiveImportExportComparisonTests.cs (1): The type or namespace name 'Office' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

By default we won't have office installed on our build agent boxes and ideally I'd like to avoid this.

Does anyone know if simply installing the `Primary Interop Assemblies (PIA)` from microsoft would cover the requirement for the Office namespace? or do we really need to install office on the build agents?

Answer (score 1):

For compiling you don't need office, but for testing you need to install office on the buildserver, which is the same bit version (x64 or x86) as the tooling you are compiled and run test for.

Comment: You are right, additionally it may be worth knowing that even with the MS office application installed that was needed you can't run these kind of tests without running TFS in 'interactive' mode. Which then means when someone logs off, all your builds stop :s

Comment: A common trick against this, is to also install an interactive test agent on the machine. This automatically sets the "log on interactive" which allows you to conveniantly run it as a logged on user after a reboot on the console.